# Use where in Rails and check only first element

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

Is it possible to, using only Rails, check first element in a join table?

Should be the same as:

```
User.includes(:articles).select {|u| !u.articles.first.voided? }
```

But with Rails 'where' statement is:

```
where("articles.first.status != 'voided'")
```

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: just added 2nd part, I need the same but with 'where'

Comment: you want to select user whose first article is not voided.. right ?

Comment: @G.B,  exactly this is what I want

Answer (score 0):

If your db is postgres and you can add first agg function than it should look like `User.select('users.*').includes(:articles).group('users.id').where("FIRST(articles.status) != 'voided'")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Article.includes(:user).first.status
```

will give you first article status.try it pls